# Android 2.1: can't run HelloWorld on the Emulator

Tags: android

I'm new in Android. I'm starting with HelloWorld program, but I can't run it on the Emulator. I'm using newest version of Eclipse and Android SDK. I also set up development environment as follows instructions on http://developer.android.com/index.html.

Does anybody have advice for me?

Comment: Where in the process are you having issues?  Just when you get to the "Run" portion?  Is there anything in the Console output?  Need more detail.

Comment: I haven't met any error. I inserted a breakpoint at the first line of onCreate() method but nothing happened. That proved the emulator didn't load the program on starting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG!!! My problem is nothing :)) i must wait the emulator in a long time after that my program will be loaded. I watched a tutorial clip on YOUTUBE and i saw the boot screen of the emulator is as like as the emulator in my machine. Thanks all for help!

Comment: I wonder how faster it would be if the emulator (and the entire framework) were written in C++.

Comment: please share the youtube link. i am wondering how slow this thing actually is. I am running mine from the command-line because I know Eclipse is a big fat Java baby so it would be slow anyways. combining that with the Android SDK may be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors?

if this is your first app, its probably to do with setup and enviroment. Whats your system spec?

---

I found running the install process - you have to make sure you follow the installation process in a good sequence. Eclipse, android platform. Java enviroment then ADT plugin.

the AVD Manager updater should have taken a long time to get everything you need when you run it. 
If it failed - There is a little check box in the settings of the AVD manager that allows you to force download the HTTP -

But as long as you've got the lot, and your building a 2.1 file. 
Also, the first time you run the emulator, it'll sit quiet for a worrying amount of time. Just make tea, watch TV - google kayden kross and it'll be fine.

---

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create an emulator image (AVD) or you won't be able to run it.

Comment: Yeah! I created an AVD before run the program. The emulator run but didn't load the program.

Answer (score 0):

also for other newbies , just right click the project and say "debug as -> android" .